# PHP GetEnV Returns same username on same network

Tags: php, getenv

I have tried to run getenv username code shown below and it shows correct username on my PC but when I access the same from other PC on same network by my ip he also gets my username. His username on his PC should be shown when he access my PC URL

Thanks

```
<?php echo getenv("username");
```

User name expectations pf windows logged in user 
On my machine it comes correct but on all machines on network show my username on their PC's if accessed by my ip

Thanks

Comment: The PHP execution is relative to the server where the PHP resides, are you distributing this code to multiple computers?

Comment: It resides on my PC where xamnp running when I did same at my home and accessed from another PC it showed me username of other PC. Now, how can I get client username ?? Any way?? Or if i put same on server would it fetch all client usernames? Or only of server?